# Is there a way to get predicted returns from a predicted covariance matrix?

Tags: pca, finance

To obtain an "eigenportfolio" of returns based on PCA analysis of the covariance matrix of a basket of $M$ stocks, we have the formula [[1]](https://www.math.nyu.edu/faculty/avellane/AvellanedaLeeStatArb071108.pdf#page=9)[[2]](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1910.02310.pdf#page=3)

$$
P = RW_k\Lambda^{1/2}_k
$$

where

- $R$ is a matrix of returns (transposed: $N\times M$)
- $W_k$ is a matrix of the first $k<M$ eigenvectors of the covariance matrix
- $\Lambda_k$ is a matrix of the first $k<M$ sorted eigenvalues

So $P$ can be thought of a portfolio of the dominant ($k$) factors in the basket of stocks.

To obtain $P$, we need returns $R$ up to the current time $T$. Say I have a prediction of the covariance matrix at time $T+10$, $\Sigma^{(T+10)}$; from this, I can obtain $W_k^{(T+10)}$ and $\Lambda_k^{(T+10)}$.

**Is there some way to use $\Sigma^{(T+10)}$ to predict $R^{(T+10)}$, the returns at $T+10$?**

I would have thought there would be a formula similar to the one above, but I haven't managed to find any resources that explicitly show this.

Comment: I would say that because $P$ is a function of $R$ it's an ill-defined problem. You would have to keep the portfolio $P$ fixed which wouldn't be a good predictor for $R$